# Photoshop - how to get my cursor back to normal?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am not sure what I did, I was messing around with some options under the Windows menu, and somehow my cursor became a circle :) and I am not sure how to get out of this mode :)

I tried to capture an image of how my cursor looks like, but the screenshot is not capturing the cursor for some reason.

Any idea how to get my photoshop cursor back to normal? Sorry for such a dumb question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressing the caps lock key will make the cursor a circle, and pressing the shift key will make it the precision cursor again.

Comment: I run into this all the time. I'm ashamed that it was such an easy solution.